# JavaScript - Map through an array and return another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, array-map

I have this simple function, that returns an array based on a condition:

```
const operationPerResource = (resource: ResourceTypes): OperationTypes[] => {
  const operations = cases[resource] || cases.default;
  return operations;
};
```

And I want to use that Function to iterate over an Array of Object with a {labe: string, value: string} type.

So, I create a simple `map`:

```
    const resources = transformEnumToArray(ResourceTypes);

    const operations = operationPerResource(resources[0].value).map((value: any) => ({
      label: value,
      value
    }));
```

The above function gives the results only for the first item in the array. I want to iterate over all the items of the Array `resources` in our case, and depending on which one I choose, I get back the available operations.

THE PROBLEM:
I have a select-box. Each select-box is populated by resources. Every time, I select a resource, I want to print the correct output. So, I used the `operationPerResource` function to return the available operations for each resource:

But, the resources are an Array of Objects, so, I need to iterate over them, in order to get back the correct Operations every time:

```
exmaple:
  Resource: Name1 => Operations for Name1[3 Items]
  Resource: Name2 => Operations for Name2[2 Items]
  Resource: Name3 => Operations for Name3[5 Items]
```

And so on and so on. If I click on a specific resoure I get back the expected results each time. I just want to make it dynamic..

> I only want to print the results of each resource not all of the results together.

I am kinda stuck here. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I'm having difficulties understanding what you want to do. Do you just need to call `map` on each element of `resources[0].value` transfoerm by `operationPerResource`? Is that what you need?

Comment: `operationPerResource(ResourceTypes.TheOneYouWant)` ?

Comment: I want to iterate over the list. And the `operationPerResource` will return the correct array, each time. Basically, I want to iterate, to find the correct value.

Comment: @DimitrisEfst I'm slightly more confused than I previously was. Mind giving an input and output example?

Comment: I updated the descriptions as best as I could. Sorry if I confused you.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is to map `resources` array with a nested map() of array returned from `operationPerResource()`

```
const operations = resources.map((r) => {
  return operationPerResource(r.value).map((value: any) => ({
      label: value,
      value
    })
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to iterate over all the resource types then aggregate all the mapping results from each of those. As a result you essentially are creating an array of arrays. You can flatten these following logic similar to:

```
const resourceTypes = transformEnumToArray(ResourceTypes);

const operations = [];

resourceTypes.forEach(resourceType => {
    const operationsForResource = operationsPerResource(resourceType.value);
    Array.prototype.push.apply(operations, operationsForResource.map((value: any) => ({
        label: value,
        value
    })));
});
```

`operations` will then contain all of the map results aggregated in one array.